In Linux kernel, where's the function that prints a character to a text VGA console?
I am reading Linux's source code, hoping to build a better understanding of its architecture. My goal is to reduce it to a minimal "hello, world" binary, removing as much unrelated code as possible. Here's the version I'm working on at the time of writing this question:
https://github.com/d33tah/minimal-kernel-build/tree/feb6e7/minified
I have a minimal initrd that prints "Hello, world" via a sys_write syscall to a VGA console. I'm looking for the routine that sends the characters to the VGA device. While looking at vgacon.c, I found the following:
const struct consw vga_con = {
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
        .con_startup = vgacon_startup,
        .con_init = vgacon_init,
        .con_deinit = vgacon_deinit,
        .con_clear = vgacon_clear,
        .con_putc = vgacon_putc,
        .con_putcs = vgacon_putcs,
        .con_cursor = vgacon_cursor,
        .con_scroll = vgacon_scroll,
        .con_switch = vgacon_switch,
        .con_blank = vgacon_blank,
        .con_font_set = vgacon_font_set,
        .con_font_get = vgacon_font_get,
        .con_resize = vgacon_resize,
        .con_set_palette = vgacon_set_palette,
        .con_scrolldelta = vgacon_scrolldelta,
        .con_set_origin = vgacon_set_origin,
        .con_save_screen = vgacon_save_screen,
        .con_build_attr = vgacon_build_attr,
        .con_invert_region = vgacon_invert_region,
};
EXPORT_SYMBOL(vga_con);

Unfortunately, the only self-evident functions are vgacon_putc and vgacon_putcs, which are explicitly defined as empty:
drivers/video/console/vgacon.c:1188:static void vgacon_putc(struct vc_data *vc, int c, int ypos, int xpos) { }
drivers/video/console/vgacon.c:1189:static void vgacon_putcs(struct vc_data *vc, const unsigned short *s,
drivers/video/console/vgacon.c-1190-                     int count, int ypos, int xpos) { }

I tried adding an extra "return" to most of the functions exposed here to find one that's essential and reading the ones that broke the flow, but I couldn't find any obvious one. Is this in another file? Why are those routines empty? Is the tty code writing characters directly to some buffer that vgacon driver uses?

When downvoting, I would appreciate some feedback on what makes this a bad question. Is it off topic? Have I done not enough research?

Some people on here downvote when they don't understand the question. Linux has layers of stuff between text and VGA. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/fb/fbcon.html

@stark thanks. Is the link relevant though? There's no fbcon in my source tree.

It depends if you mean VGA graphics (frame buffer) mode or VGA text mode. For VGA text mode, there are calls to the scr_writew macro from "drivers/tty/vt/vt.c" that physically write characters and character attributes to locations in VGA text mode memory.

Looks like the case is closed, thanks to @IanAbbott! :)

As Ian Abbott pointed out in his comment to this question, the code I was looking for is in vc_con_write_normal(). There's the following line there:
scr_writew(tc, (u16 *)vc->vc_pos);

Commenting it out disables output. It's defined in the following way:
include/linux/vt_buffer.h:24:
#define scr_writew(val, addr) (*(addr) = (val))

If I understand it correctly, vc_pos gets initiated to vc_origin, which is initiated to vga_vram_base, which is one of the two addresses, so running
$ grep -n -r -B2 'vga_vram_base = 0x'

gives these two pieces in drivers/video/console/vgacon.c respectively:
     if (screen_info.orig_video_mode == 7) {
             /* Monochrome display */
             vga_vram_base = 0xb0000;
...
             /* If not, it is color. */
             vga_can_do_color = true;
             vga_vram_base = 0xb8000;

